# VBA - open all excel files from hard drive

Tags: excel, file, directory, disk

i saw many codes that open excel files from specific folder.
Could You please help me to make a code that will go through every folder on my hard disk?
I know it sounds big, but ye - that's what i need..

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference to **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** (**Tools** -> **References...**). Then you can write code like the following:

```vb
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

Sub ParseFolder(fldr As Folder)
    Dim subfolder As Folder
    For Each subfolder in fldr.Subfolders
        ParseFolder subfolder
    Next

    Dim f As File
    For Each f In fldr.Files
        Select Case fso.GetExtensionName(file.path)
            Case "xls", "xlsb", "xlsm"
                
                ' Do something with Excel file here

        End Select
    Next
End Sub

Sub Main
    ' Run this macro to start the process running
    ParseFolder fso.GetFolder("C:\")
End Sub
```

Depending on how many Excel files you have on disk, you may want to target your code to only a smaller subset of Excel files, or to a smaller subset of folders; or to use `DoEvents` so the application doesn't freeze.

---

**References**

Scripting Runtime

- [**FileSystemObject** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) -- [**GetExtensionName**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getextensionname-method) and [**GetFolder**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getfolder-method) methods
- [**Folder** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/folder-object) -- [**Subfolders**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/subfolders-property) and [**Files**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/files-property) properties